# Problems in understanding recursive in python

Tags: python

hope you all had a good day. Just a question, I just stumble on this question which have this program but it doesn't have a name so i'll will just call it walk.py

```
def walk(n, count):
    if count > 0:
        if n % 3 == 0:
           return walk(n/3, count -1)
        else:
           return walk(2*n + 1, count -1)
    return n
```

So that is the program.
The question said what will the result be if the input is n = 10 and count = 7.

so   `print(walk(10, 7))`

and the output of the program is `47` which i don't understand why.

then i try to plug in a different input `print(walk(11, 7))`
and the output is `1535`

it is very confusing, last input is `print(walk(12, 6))`
and the output is `1.0`

Please explain this to me, thanks.

Thank for suggesting the solution to me.
I have understand how the things work with the suggestion of slowly change the parameters and the recursive.

So with the new program,

instead of return function, I have `print(f"This is when n is divisible by 3 {walk(n/3, count - 1)}")`

and the same for the `else` which is `print(f"This is when n is not divisible by 3 {walk(2*n-1, count - 1}")`.

So with that i got the result `This is when n is not divisible by 3 23.0 This is when n is not divisible by 3 11.0 This is when n is divisible by 3 5.0 15`

Comment: Step through the code statement by statement. There is nothing else *we* would do.

Comment: The function is recursive so kindly try printing the values passed as parameters in each recursive call to understand it.

Comment: It's something close to Collatz Conjecture. Watch this for better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=094y1Z2wpJg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When n = 10 and count = 7,

```
def walk(10, 7):
if count > 0:  # 7 > 0
    if n % 3 == 0:  # 10 % 3 != 0
       return walk(n/3, count -1)
    else:   # as if statement is false, else statement is executed
       return walk(2*n + 1, count -1) # recursive call of walk() function
return n
```

Function gets recursively called until first if-statement is false ( count is not > 0)

count variable is decremented by 1 in every call of the function. Hence, it will run 7 times until count = 0

After which, the final return statement ( return n ) is the final answer.

Follow the same process for each of your values and you will reach your answer!